# Расшифровка приватным ключем

Tags: php, openssl

Получаю ответ по апи дешифрую их и вот что на выходе получается:

```
$value = "W9g/l6UH6L0cYpA8GZML2eFTJQPkALvr/npCR3YWovIUsAZNOJMu3FWRlNyEb/YS0MZTpwpKZQPc8q9L7+cUQfdEa/QGdieW+qz8H6aZ1BTYzp4so4Rn0giSNOAbZHOV";
$key   = hex2bin("e0454a719e54a32d5f1f2877f356fceb");

$method = "AES-128-CBC";
$decryptedData = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($value), $method, $key, 0, $iv);
```

Загвоздка состоит в том что передавать в $iv, c шифрованием столкнулся недавно, поэтому совсем зеленый в этом деле

Answer (score 1):

`$iv` - это какой-то текст. Этот вектор используется для того, чтобы одно и те же данные в зашифрованном виде выглядели по-разному. Например, если кто-то как-то узнает, что фамилия "Петров" в зашифрованном виде выглядит как "ZML2eFTJQPkA", то без `$iv` легко найдут всех остальных Петровых, если шифрование глобальное. Да и вообще тогда смогут расшифровать все данные. Поэтому в идеале для каждой строки в БД должен быть свой `$iv`, который можно хранить там же. Генерируйте его рандомно. Для примера

```
//salt получаем $salt=bin2hex(random_bytes(8));

function my_crypt($salt, $password, $data_to_crypt)
{
    $method='AES-256-CTR';
    $crypt_key=my_hash_pbkdf2($salt, $password);
    $options=true;
    $iv=$salt; //для наглядности

    return bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($data_to_crypt, $method, $crypt_key, $options, $iv));
}

function my_decrypt($salt, $password, $data_to_decrypt)
{
    $data=hex2bin($data_to_decrypt);
    $method='AES-256-CTR';
    $crypt_key=my_hash_pbkdf2($salt, $password);
    $options=true;
    $iv=$salt; //для наглядности

    return openssl_decrypt($data, $method, $crypt_key, $options, $iv);  
}

function my_hash_pbkdf2($salt, $password)
{
    $algo='sha256';
    $iterations=100;
    $length=32;
    $raw_output=true;

    return hash_pbkdf2($algo, $password, $salt, $iterations, $length, $raw_output);
}
```

Если у вас php от 7.2 включительно, то используйте [Sodium](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sodium.php)